# How to reduce query execution time for table with huge data

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

I am running this query in production(Oracle) and it is taking more than 3 minutes .  Is there any way out to reduce the execution time ? Both svc_order and event table contains almost 1million records .

```
select 0 test_section, count(1) count, 'DD' test_section_value  
from svc_order so, event e  
where so.svc_order_id = e.svc_order_id  
  and so.entered_date >= to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')  
  and e.event_type = 230 and e.event_level = 'O'  
  and e.current_sched_date between 
      to_date( '09/01/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
      and to_date('09/29/2013 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
  and (((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type = 0)) 
       or  ((so.sots_ta is null) and (so.action_type = 0)) 
       or  ((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type is null)))
  and so.company_code = 'LL'
```

Comment: "I cannot create index" . Why not? And 50 to 60k records is certainly not a huge amount of data.

Comment: Can we do it in java code ? If yes , then how ?

Comment: What has Java got to do with it?

Comment: Ignore that . Do you have a solution for it ? How can I proceed ?

Comment: You want to drive a nail and you cannot use a hammer. That's fine (we all face ridiculous restrictions in real-life work) but you should be more explicit about the circumstances that lead you to that so we can provide useful advice. E.g. "Iron tools are not allowed because we work under strong magnetic fields".

Comment: where is the `Group By` clause?

Comment: @FlorinGhita: No need for one.

Comment: ouch, I did't observed he actually don't select anything from tables. It just counts.

Comment: @RahulSingh update your post with an execution plan please

Comment: I would try with a hint `/*+use_hash(so e)*/`

Comment: We have index for the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the what you said that you cannot create indexes. I hope that the query is making a full table scan on the table. Please try a parallel hint.

```
select /*+ full(so) parallel(so, 4) */ 0 test_section, count(1) count, 'DD' test_section_value  
from svc_order so, event e  
where so.svc_order_id = e.svc_order_id  
  and so.entered_date >= to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')  
  and e.event_type = 230 and e.event_level = 'O'  
  and e.current_sched_date between 
      to_date( '09/01/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
      and to_date('09/29/2013 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
  and (((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type = 0)) 
       or  ((so.sots_ta is null) and (so.action_type = 0)) 
       or  ((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type is null)))
  and so.company_code = 'LL'
```

Comment: This solution reduced query execution time considerably. One more addition we have indexes . Can you help in making the better ?

Answer (score 0):

You could *at least* avoid the triple AND/OR list by using `COALESCE()` (or its oracle equivalent `IFNULL()` ) Note: this does not catch the case where *both* sots_ta and action_type are NULL.

```
SELECT 0 test_section, count(1) count, 'DD' test_section_value
FROM svc_order so 
JOIN event e  ON so.svc_order_id = e.svc_order_id
WHERE e.event_type = 230 and e.event_level = 'O'  
  AND so.entered_date >= to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND e.current_sched_date >= to_date('09/01/2010 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  AND e.current_sched_date  < to_date('10/01/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
  AND  COALESCE(so.sots_ta, 'N') = 'N'
  AND  COALESCE(so.action_type, 0) = 0   
  AND so.company_code = 'LL'
```

I replaced the between by a plain `t >= low AND t. < high)` test because I don't like `between`s semantics. I replaced the `FROM kommalist` by a `JOIN` because I like joins better.

Comment: Thanks , but I did not see much difference in execution time .

Comment: No wonder. It's basically the same. We can't really help you when you don't answer our questions in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have additional indexes but tables must have at least meaning full primary key, right so is there one?  That should result in at least index, non/clustered, anything. 
Look at it lets and try to make use of it.

In case table is a heap, and we want to deal with it as it is, then we should reduce the number rows in each table individually by applying respective where filters and then combine that result set. 
In your query only meaning full result column depends on base tables is count(1). Other two columns are constants.
Because also JOIN/Cartesian Product etc….. will lead DB engine to look for Indexes so instead use INTERSECT which I feel should better in your case.
Some other changes you can do:
Avoid using TO_DATE or any kind of function in Right Side of the WHERE condition column. Prepare data in  local Variable and use Local Variable in query.
Also you need to check is there any good performance gain using >= than BETWEEN ?

I have modified the query and also combined one redundant where condition. 
Remember that if this changes works for you right now that doesn’t mean it will work always.  As son your table start hitting more data that qualifies those WHERE conditions this swill again come back as slow query. so for short term this might work but longer term you have to think about alternate options

```
    1)  for example Indexed Views on top of this tables
    2)  Create same tables with different name and sync data 
        between new and original table using  “Insert/Update/Delete Trigger”.




    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [COUNT], 'DD' test_section_value  ,0 test_section
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  so.svc_order_id
        FROM    svc_order so
        WHERE   so.entered_date >= to_date('01/01/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                AND so.company_code = 'LL'

        INTERSECT

        SELECT  e.svc_order_id
        FROM    event e
        WHERE   e.event_type = 230
                AND e.event_level = 'O'
                AND e.current_sched_date BETWEEN
                    to_date('09/01/2010 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                    AND to_date('09/29/2013 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                AND ( 
                        (( so.sots_ta = 'N' ) AND ( so.action_type IS NULL OR so.action_type = 0))
                        OR 
                        (( so.sots_ta IS NULL ) AND ( so.action_type = 0 )) 
                        --or ((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type is null))
                    )
    )qry1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure statistics are up-to-date.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('[schema]', 'svc_order');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('[schema]', 'event');
end;
/
```

This query is a very simple join between two small tables, but with complex predicates.
You almost certainly do *not* want to significantly re-write all of your queries in search of some magic syntax that will make everything run fast.  Yes, there are some rare cases where `BETWEEN` does not work well, or moving the predicates into an inline view helps, or replacing the join with an `INTERSECT` might help.  But that sounds like [cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) to me.  Ask yourself, *why* would those changes make any difference?  If those types of changes always improved performance, why wouldn't Oracle just translate the queries internally?

Normally, you should try to provide better information to the optimizer so it can make better decisions.  Usually this is as simple as gathering statistics with the default settings.  Some predicates are just too complex, and for that you should try to use
[dynamic sampling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#i42991), such as `/*+ dynamic_sampling(6) */`.  Or maybe
add some [histograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#i42219).  Or perhaps add an [expression statistic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/stats.htm#BEICJCJH) like this:

```
SELECT 
    DBMS_STATS.CREATE_EXTENDED_STATS(null,'SVC_ORDER',
        '(((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type = 0)) 
        or  ((so.sots_ta is null) and (so.action_type = 0)) 
        or  ((so.sots_ta = 'N') and (so.action_type is null)))'
    ) 
FROM DUAL;
--Don't forget to re-gather statistics after this.
```

The optimizer is probably under-estimating the number of rows, and using a nested loop instead of a hash join.  After providing it with more information, ideally it will start using a hash join.  But at some point, after you've tried the above methods and possibly many other features, you can just tell it what kind of join to use.  Which would be @Florin Ghita's suggestion, `/*+use_hash(so e)*/`.