# Query tuning Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

While executing below query am getting more than 45 minutes to take run. I tried my level best to tune but I didn't reduce the time.can any one help me to reduce the time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dte_Errors be1
WHERE BE1.source_name = 'TOS_TABIN235_1'
  AND (be1.source_name, be1.PK_VALUE) IN (SELECT be.source_name, be.PK_VALUE
                                          FROM dte_Errors be 
                                          INNER JOIN stg_tabin235 stg235 ON substr(BE.pk_Value, 1, 9) = to_char(stg235.package_id) 
                                                                         AND substr(BE.pk_Value, -9) = stg235.departure_date
                                          INNER JOIN dte_ext_lookup lkp ON lkp.package_id = stg235.package_id
                                          INNER JOIN ATC.EX_PACK_235@TROTROREAD_COMRES atcom235 ON atcom235.ext_package_id  = substr(lkp.ext_pkg_id_with_season, 1, 49)
                                          WHERE BE.source_name = 'TOS_TABIN235_1'
                                            AND stg235.departure_date = atcom235.departure_date
                                            AND SUBSTR(atcom235.EXT_PACKAGE_ID, 2, 4) NOT IN  ('IAIL1','ICLL1','IMAL1','ITUL1')
                                            AND stg235.departure_date  BETWEEN '01-NOV-12' AND '31-OCT-16');
```

Comment: [We need more information](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html). [Edit] your question and add the definition of the tables (as `create table` statements, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please), all defined indexes and the execution plan (also as _formatted_ text, no screen shots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query checks whether a `dte_errors` record itself or another with the same `source_name` and `pk_value` has matches in the other tables with certain criteria. I cannot say of course whether this is what the query is supposed to do. I assume it is, but it *may be* that you only want to check the record itself. In that case remove the `dte_errors` access from the subquery.

That you access `pk_value` substrings, results from `dte_errors` being a mere general log table, so this is okay. That you work on substrings of `lkp.ext_pkg_id_with_season` and `atcom235.ext_package_id`, however, seems strange. If the substrings contain separate information, then why aren't they separate columns? This may be already be part of your problem.

As to the join criteria, it would be good to access columns directly, rather than converted. As mentioned the `pk_value` must be converted with `SUBSTR`, but must the `stg235.package_id` be converted with `TO_CHAR`? If `substr(BE.pk_Value,1,9)` can safely be converted with `TO_NUMBER` (i.e. it is guaranteed to always contain numbers only), then you should change `substr(BE.pk_Value,1,9) = to_char(stg235.package_id)` to `to_number(substr(BE.pk_Value,1,9)) = stg235.package_id`. If this cannot be done safely you can use this instead: `to_number(regexp_substr(BE.pk_Value, '^\d{9}$')) = stg235.package_id`.

Thus you'd join both `dte_errors` and `dte_ext_lookup` to `stg235.package_id` and not one to `stg235.package_id` and the other to `to_char(stg235.package_id)`.

Your use of `departure_date` seems a bit fuzzy. The fact that you use `stg235.departure_date  between '01-NOV-12' AND '31-OCT-16'` makes me assume that it is a column of type `DATE`. (Otherwise that would be a mere string comparision with rather unexpected results.) However, `'01-NOV-12'` AND `'31-OCT-16'` *are* strings. Your DBMS may be able to convert them implicitely to dates, but you rely on session settings here. The query would crash on my system for instance, as `OCT` has no meaning in German. Use date literals instead: `DATE'2012-11-01'`and `DATE'2016-10-31'`. You should also explicitely convert `to_date(substr(BE.pk_Value,-9), 'DD-MON-YY') = stg235.departure_date` instead of `substr(BE.pk_Value,-9) = stg235.departure_date` where the same thing is done implicitely (again relying on session settings).

I suggest the following indexes:

- `dte_errors(source_name, pk_value)`. Because this is how you link one dte_errors record to the others (provided this is really desired).
- `dte_errors(source_name, to_number(substr(pk_value,1,9)), to_date(substr(pk_Value,-9), 'DD-MON-YY'), pk_value)`. This functional index can speed up your join with `stg_tabin235`.
- `stg_tabin235(package_id, departure_date)`. For the join with `dte_ext_lookup` and `dte_errors` and `atcom235`.
- `dte_ext_lookup(package_id)`. Of course.
- `dte_ext_lookup(substr(ext_pkg_id_with_season,1,49))`. But better have a separate column `ext_package_id` and index that instead.
- `atcom235(ext_package_id, departure_date, substr(atcom235.ext_package_id,2,4))`. Because these are the fields you use to access the table's records.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check are you joining tables with indexed columns, also check with joins and 
Check ([How to reduce query execution time for table with huge data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136444/how-to-reduce-query-execution-time-for-table-with-huge-data)"  this may help you)